# After restore of disposed UITextBox the text is pale

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I have the logic of disposing of lines in my chart and have a custom cursor that [I get from this link](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0702-customCursor.html?theme=lightNew&page-theme=light) and when I dispose the line the label shouldn't show too and it works, but after restoring the rowY the names in textbox is pale, look at the next screenshots [pale labels image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoDLy.png), [normal labels before disposing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KY93.png)

```
rowsY.map((rowY, i) => {
 this.seriesInstances[i][1].isDisposed() ? rowY.dispose() : rowY.restore();
 if (nearestDataPoints[i]?.location?.y) {
  rowY.setText(`${this.seriesInstances[i][1].getName()}: ${+this.chartInstance.getDefaultAxisY().formatValue(nearestDataPoints[i].location.y)} ${this.seriesInitialData[i].unit}`)
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you dispose/restore rowY in **onSeriesBackgroundMouseMove**.
I'd suggest to do that in the place where you dispose/restore the seriesInstances but still it will not work with legend box.
To fix it you can just dispose RowsY and RowX instead of resultTable and restore it after check:

```
rowX.restore()
series.forEach((el, i)=>{       
   //check if series was disposed
   if(!el.isDisposed()){
      rowsY[i].restore() 
   }
})
```

Also, in v.4.0 we will add new API that replaces dispose/restore

Here is updated code from the example that you use

```
// Import LightningChartJS
const lcjs = require("@arction/lcjs");

// Import data-generators from 'xydata'-library.
const { createProgressiveTraceGenerator } = require("@arction/xydata");

// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
  lightningChart,
  AutoCursorModes,
  UIElementBuilders,
  UILayoutBuilders,
  UIOrigins,
  translatePoint,
  Themes,
} = lcjs;

// Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart()
    .ChartXY({
        theme: Themes.lightNew,
    })
    // Disable native AutoCursor to create custom
    .setAutoCursorMode(AutoCursorModes.disabled)
    .setTitle('Custom Cursor using LCJS UI')

// set title for Y axis
chart.getDefaultAxisY().setTitle('Y-axis')

// generate data and creating the series
const series = new Array(3).fill(0).map((_, iSeries) => {
    const nSeries = chart.addLineSeries({
        dataPattern: {
            // pattern: 'ProgressiveX' => Each consecutive data point has increased X coordinate.
            pattern: 'ProgressiveX',
        },
    })

    createProgressiveTraceGenerator()
    .setNumberOfPoints(200)
    .generate()
    .toPromise()
    .then((data) => {
        return nSeries.add(data)
    })
    return nSeries
})

// Add Legend.
const legend = chart.addLegendBox().add(chart)

// Create UI elements for custom cursor.
const resultTable = chart
    .addUIElement(UILayoutBuilders.Column, {
        x: chart.getDefaultAxisX(),
        y: chart.getDefaultAxisY(),
    })
    .setMouseInteractions(false)
    .setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftBottom)
    .setMargin(5)
    .setBackground((background) =>
        background
            // Style same as Theme result table.
            .setFillStyle(chart.getTheme().resultTableFillStyle)
            .setStrokeStyle(chart.getTheme().resultTableStrokeStyle),
    )

const rowX = resultTable.addElement(UILayoutBuilders.Row).addElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox)

const rowsY = series.map((el, i) => {
    return resultTable
        .addElement(UILayoutBuilders.Row)
        .addElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox)
        .setTextFillStyle(series[i].getStrokeStyle().getFillStyle())
})

const tickX = chart.getDefaultAxisX().addCustomTick().setAllocatesAxisSpace(false)

const ticksY = series.map((el, i) => {
    return chart
        .getDefaultAxisY()
        .addCustomTick()
        .setAllocatesAxisSpace(false)
        .setMarker((marker) => marker.setTextFillStyle(series[i].getStrokeStyle().getFillStyle()))
})

// Hide custom cursor components initially.
// resultTable.dispose()
rowsY.forEach(el=>{
    el.dispose()
})
tickX.dispose()
ticksY.forEach((tick) => tick.dispose())


// Implement custom cursor logic with events.
chart.onSeriesBackgroundMouseMove((_, event) => {
    const mouseLocationClient = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY }
    // Translate mouse location to LCJS coordinate system for solving data points from series, and translating to Axes.
    const mouseLocationEngine = chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine(mouseLocationClient.x, mouseLocationClient.y)

    // Translate mouse location to Axis.
    const mouseLocationAxis = translatePoint(mouseLocationEngine, chart.engine.scale, series[0].scale)

    // Solve nearest data point to the mouse on each series.
    const nearestDataPoints = series.map((el) => el.solveNearestFromScreen(mouseLocationEngine))

    // Find the nearest solved data point to the mouse.
    const nearestPoint = nearestDataPoints.reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
        if (!prev) return curr
        if (!curr) return prev
        return Math.abs(mouseLocationAxis.y - curr.location.y) < Math.abs(mouseLocationAxis.y - prev.location.y) ? curr : prev
    })

    if (nearestPoint) {
        // Set custom cursor location.
        resultTable.setPosition({
            x: nearestPoint.location.x,
            y: nearestPoint.location.y,
        })

        // Change origin of result table based on cursor location.
        if (nearestPoint.location.x > chart.getDefaultAxisX().getInterval().end / 1.5) {
            if (nearestPoint.location.y > chart.getDefaultAxisY().getInterval().end / 1.5) {
                resultTable.setOrigin(UIOrigins.RightTop)
            } else {
                resultTable.setOrigin(UIOrigins.RightBottom)
            }
        } else if (nearestPoint.location.y > chart.getDefaultAxisY().getInterval().end / 1.5) {
            resultTable.setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftTop)
        } else {
            resultTable.setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftBottom)
        }

        // Format result table text.
        rowX.setText(`X: ${chart.getDefaultAxisX().formatValue(nearestPoint.location.x)}`)
        rowsY.forEach((rowY, i) => {
            rowY.setText(`Y${i}: ${chart.getDefaultAxisY().formatValue(nearestDataPoints[i]?.location.y || 0)}`)
        })

        // Position custom ticks.
        tickX.setValue(nearestPoint.location.x)
        ticksY.forEach((tick, i) => {
            tick.setValue(nearestDataPoints[i]?.location.y || 0)
        })

        // Display cursor.
        rowX.restore()
        series.forEach((el, i)=>{       
            if(!el.isDisposed()){
                rowsY[i].restore() 
            }
        })
        
        tickX.restore()
        ticksY.map((el) => el.restore())
    } else {
        // Hide cursor.
        disposeCustomCursor()
        tickX.dispose()
        ticksY.map((el) => el.dispose())
    }
})

chart.onSeriesBackgroundMouseLeave((_, e) => {
    disposeCustomCursor()
    tickX.dispose()
    ticksY.map((el) => el.dispose())
})

chart.onSeriesBackgroundMouseDragStart((_, e) => {
    disposeCustomCursor()
    tickX.dispose()
    ticksY.map((el) => el.dispose())
})


function disposeCustomCursor() {
    rowX.dispose()
    rowsY.forEach(el=>{
        el.dispose()
    })
}

setTimeout(() => {
    series[0].dispose()
    rowsY[0].dispose() 
}, 3000);



setTimeout(() => {
    series[0].restore()
    rowsY[0].restore() 
}, 6000);
```